# Elastic Beanstalk with AWS-CDK on higher level than resources

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a Elastic Beanstalk application that is deployed with a CloudFormation json config.
I'm looking into the Cloud Development Kit atm and try to replicate the CloudFormation config I have right now from an CDK app.
But I can't find any Info according to create an Elastic Beanstalk app in CDK on higher level. If I got it right, the aim is, to write less config code and still get the same cloudformation executed.

I started experimenting using the CfnApplication from the elastic beanstalk package, but according to what I read, using any Cfn* things means I'm on the low-level end again where it's the same effort creating the configs. But I'm unable to find anything higher-level for ElasticBeanstalk :/

Therefore the question: is it even implemented yet, or did I not find what I search for?

Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a working sample environment using this:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/elasticbeanstalk/elasticbeanstalk-environment

It does what they say it should, in that it chooses sensible defaults, but this is just a jumping off point, as it is just a sample application.  For customization, you set the attributes that are important to you, and the rest is autogenerated.

One thing to note, though - this example threw an error for me until I added the `solutionStackName` parameter.  The example has this:

```js
    new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: 'MySampleEnvironment',
      applicationName: app.applicationName,
      platformArn: platform
    });
```

and this is the working block:

```js
    new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: 'MySampleEnvironment',
      applicationName: app.applicationName,
      platformArn: platform,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.10 running Docker 18.06.1-ce'
    });
```

The solution stack value just needs to be the [valid solution stack name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported) for the platform you are running.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I cannot get cdk to deploy the example even with your tip. For me it always fails:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/issues/117

When I tried your fix, I got an error that platform and solutionStack cannot be both specified.